# Storing data in a multidimensional array from dynamically generated foreach loop

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I am trying to figure out how to store images and strings in a multidimensional array. In the admin there is an option to add images (+ text) which is generated by jQuery, and looks like this:

```
foreach($images as $image){
   echo '<li><input type="hidden" id="imageURL" name="imageURL[]" value="'. $imageURL .'" /><textarea name="imageTXT[]" class="imagelist">'. $imageTXT .'</textarea>&nbsp;<input type="button" value="'. __("Remove", "sitnso") .'" class="remove" /></span></li>';
}
```

All this works fine. In Wordpress admin I am getting a list with two fields per list item, one for image URL and one for text to go along with that. The problem is more with saving. How can I store all this information into an array that looks along the lines of the below, and get the meta in the correct fields with get_post_meta?

```
Array(
    [0] => array(
        'imageURL' => 'image1.jpg',
        'imageTXT' => 'This is text written in imageTXT'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'imageURL' => 'image2.jpg',
        'imageTXT' => 'This is text written in imageTXT'
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'imageURL' => 'image3.jpg',
        'imageTXT' => 'This is text written in imageTXT'
    ),
    [3] => array(
        'imageURL' => 'image4.jpg',
        'imageTXT' => 'This is text written in imageTXT'
    )
);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May i ask, are you doing this to store extra fields in the back end? If so, you may want to look up Advanced Custom Fields. It does all of this for you.

Comment: Don't really get what you want !  You are talking about a way to get the index, keep it for another save ? Or a way to re-indexing (or simply indexing) your images when the jquery add another field ?

Comment: Hi @Benoti, I am looking to store both image and text with an array (with update_post_meta), so I can link them in the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store an array in one meta_key, you need to add your different keys in the input name. For my example, this is the retrieve way where you need to be in a foreach loop where $i is increment with $i++ in it. To save value you will need to modify your name input with ['imageUrl'][] and ['imagetxt'][].

```
$imageset = get_post_meta($post_id, 'imageset', true);
$i=0;
foreach($imageset as image){
echo '<input type="hidden" name="imageset['.$i.'][imageUrl]" value="'.$imageset[$i]['imageUrl'].'"/>';
echo '<textarea name="imageset['.$i.'][imageTxt]">'.$imageset[$i]['imageTxt'].'</textarea>';
$i++;
}
```

I didn't test it to ajust to your whishes, but I'm sure you'll get it !